# Multiple eps values in sklearn DBSCAN

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dbscan

I want to use the DBSCAN implementation from sklearn. They allow you to use a custom distance metric but only one `eps` values. 
What I want is the following:

Lets say my points have 3 features each, so each point can be considered as a numpy array of the form `p=np.array([p1,p2,p3])`. Two points `p` and `q` are neighbors if `np.abs(p1-q1) < eps1` and `np.abs(p2-q2) < eps2` and `np.abs(p3-q3) < eps3`. Usually, one would use `d(p,q)<eps`, where `d(,)` is a metric and eps a threshold.

Is there a way to implement my needs easily into sklearn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scale appropriately, and then use maximum norm.

```
p = p * [1/eps1, 1/eps2, 1/eps3]

c = sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN(eps=1, metric="chebyshev", ...)
```

Note that DBSCAN uses `<=` not `<`.

Or you precompute a binary "distance" matrix, where the distance is 0 if the three conditions hold, and 1 otherwise. But that needs O(n²) memory.

Comment: This distance matrix would be - in my case - sparse. Is there a way to exploit that so that the memory usage decreases? But your scaling idea is just beautiful! Thanks!

Comment: Since 0.17 sklearn can use a sparse distance matrix. But beware that you need to store the 0s then, not the 1s. Missing values are considered to be infinite. I wouldn't be surprised if above scaling approach turns out to be faster than the sparse matrix.

Comment: In [ELKI](https://elki-project.github.io/), you can define a distance function - and get index acceleration - without this prior weighting hack (essentially, follow [this tutorial](https://elki-project.github.io/tutorial/spatial_distance_functions) with a weighted distance). But even then, the prior weighting may be slightly faster than applying the weights on every distance computation.